# Hide <a> tag if data is NULL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, wordpress

I have a map marker website that grabs Tattoo Parlours from Google maps and adds them as a marker to our interactive map.

I have a database with a "Messenger field". Basically, some of the markers have 
a "Send message" button  tag on them where the user can message them directly.

However, not all of my markers need this  tag, so I want to hide the  tag from the marker if the data returns NULL.

Here's the code:

```
 //assign an infowindow to the marker so that when its clicked it shows the name of the place
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, x) {
                        return function () {
                            infowindow.setContent("<div class='no-scroll'><strong>" + results[x]['place']['name'] + "</strong><br><br>"
                                + results[x]['place']['address'] + "<br><br>"
                                + "<span style=\"display:table;margin:0 auto; color: #e7711b;\">"
                                + results[x]['place']['rating'] + "&nbsp;" + WPacStars.rating_render(results[x]['place']['rating'], 16, 'e7711b')
                                + "</span>"
                                +"<div id='more_info' align='center' style='margin: 0 auto;'>"
                                + "<a href='" + WPURLS.siteurl + "/reviews?place_id=" + results[x]['place']['id']
                                + "' target='_blank' style='text-align: center; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;text-decoration: none; font-size: 18px; color: #6495ed'>click here for more info</a>"
                                + "<a class="messenger-link" href='" + results[x]['place']['messenger']
                                + "' target='_blank' style='text-align: center; display: block; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none; color: #6495ed'>Send Message</a>"
                                + "</div></div>");
                            infowindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, x));
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
//}}
```

Hope someone can help/give guidance!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can add that attribute conditionally after the fact using [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).  If you've got data, add the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the `a` tag not having `href` set

```js
function removeAnchors(){
 $("a").each(function(){
  if($(this).attr("href") == "" || $(this).attr("href") == "null" || $(this).attr("href") == undefined || $(this).attr("href") == null) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
 })
}
removeAnchors(); // Call this function after adding the html dynamically
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="example.com">Send Button</a>
<a href="">Send Button</a>
<a href="">Send Button</a>
<a href="">Send Button</a>
<a href="">Send Button</a>
```

Comment: Hope you know how jquery works.You need to put this function in `.ready` block and call it after your display is rendered completely.Edited my answer a little hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your JS code with following. It might help you.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, x) {
    return function () {
        var infoContent = "<div class='no-scroll'><strong>" + results[x]['place']['name'] + "</strong><br><br>";
        infoContent += results[x]['place']['address'] + "<br><br>";
        infoContent += "<span style=\"display:table;margin:0 auto; color: #e7711b;\">";
        infoContent += "results[x]['place']['rating'] + "&nbsp;" + WPacStars.rating_render(results[x]['place']['rating'], 16, 'e7711b')</span>";
        infoContent += "<div id='more_info' align='center' style='margin: 0 auto;'>";
        infoContent += "<a href='" + WPURLS.siteurl + "/reviews?place_id=" + results[x]['place']['id'] +" target='_blank' style='text-align: center; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 5px;text-decoration: none; font-size: 18px; color: #6495ed'>click here for more info</a>";
        // this condition should be change as per your requirement as I dont know which data you want to compare with NULL value
        if(results[x]['place']['messenger'] != '' && results[x]['place']['messenger'] != null){                           
            infoContent += "<a class="messenger-link" href='" + results[x]['place']['messenger'] + "' target='_blank' style='text-align: center; display: block; text-decoration: none; font-size: 14px; text-decoration: none; color: #6495ed'>Send Message</a>";
        }
        infoContent += "</div></div>";
        infowindow.setContent(infoContent);
        infowindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
    }
})(marker, x));
```